# YUMI multiboot usb path issue

Tags: grub, bootable-media

I was create multiboot usb with YUMI software.

My bootable usb dir;

```
/bootwin7
/bootwin8
/multiboot
```

in **bootwin7** folder;

```
/boot
/efi
/sources
/bootmgr
/bootmgr.efi
```

in menu.lst;

```
#start Win7SP1
title Windows 7 SP1
root (hd0,0)
chainloader (hd0,0)/bootwin7/bootmgr
#end Win7SP1
```

I can boot my usb correctly, but when i select windows 7 i saw error;

```
Windows Boot Manager
Windows failed to start...

File : \Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc00000f
etc..
```

Comment: what else is on the bootable drive?

Comment: in multiboot folder have many folders for example; AcronisTrueImage2015_en-US, F4UBCD-4.61, HBCD15.1TR.h, ISOS, menu, mnxp etc..  and files; chain.c32, grub.exe, libcom32.c32, libutil.c32 etc..

I can boot Acronis or FalconFours, Hiren and other isos correctly. But when i select Windows 7 i saw error.

Comment: I've seen that before... The Windows installers won't load correctly unless they're on their own dedicated install drive, which is why windows refuses to complete setup. simply because YUMI can't properly emulate the drive

Comment: answer given. sadly, Windows doesn't like sharing space

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that before... The Windows installers won't load correctly unless they're on their own dedicated install drive, which is why windows refuses to complete setup. simply because YUMI can't properly emulate the drive